# Clarification of a problem in Linear Algebra concerning basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a,b,c \in \Bbb R, a\ne 0$. The set $E:=\{(x.y.z)\in \Bbb R ; ax+by+cz=0\}$ is defined on a plane in $\Bbb R^3$ which contains the origin. Let $P_E: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be the projection onto the plane $E^1$.

a)Proof that the set $B:= \{\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2}(\frac{-b}a,1,0),\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2}(\frac{-c}a,0,1),\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2}(a,b,c)\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3 $. And find the representation matrix of $P_E$ with respect to the basis $B$.

b)find the representation matrix of $P_E$ with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

c) Find a basis for kernel($P_E$)

So my first question is, it doesn't look like he part where $P_E: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ that would be projected on to $E^1$ is of any use for the 3 problems? Is that correct? I don't see

Second question is I am not quite sure i understood the notation for the set. Does  $\{\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2}(\frac{-b}a,1,0)$ mean that for the first vector consists of 3 numbers where the first one is $\frac{-b}a$ and the second is 1 and the third is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ itself contains 3-tuples of numbers (not product of them), $E\subseteq\Bbb R^3$.

To your second question, yes, almost, the first basis vector is
$$v_1=\left(\frac{-b/a}{a^2+b^2+c^2},\,\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2},\,0\right)\,.$$

You'll get the answer on your first question if you calculate exercise (b).
Assuming, $P_E$ is the *orthogonal* projection to $E$, we get
$$P_E(v_1)=v_1,\ P_E(v_2)=v_2,\ P_E(v_3)=0$$
because $v_1,v_2\in E$ while $v_3\perp E$.

You should be able to write up the matrix of $P_E$ in basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ using this information.

Comment: Ah thanks!!! another question....Sorry how do i prove that the set is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ because i tried using definition, hit a wall. i tried using matrix, hit another wall......

Comment: You can express a parallel to $(1,0,0)$ as $v_3-bv_1-cv_2$, then you can express $(0,1,0)$ using $v_1$ and $(0,0,1)$ using $v_2$, hence $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is a generator system.

Comment: I am not quite sure i understood that method. Are you saying since they are supposed to be the basis for $\Bbb R^3$ they have to be in elementary basis vectors? But why are you using $v_3-bv_1-cv_2$ for $(1,0,0)$ I am not quite sure i understood you correctly.--.-

Comment: What do you get when you calculate the coordinates of $v_3-bv_1-cv_2$? If you can express all vectors in a basis by linear combinations of $v_i$, you can express *all* vectors by linear combinations of $v_i$.

Comment: I get $v_3-bv_1-cv_2=(\frac{1}a,0,0)$. So since they are in a plane i can set $\frac{1}a=1$? Is this the idea? Similarly, $V_1=(\frac{-b/a}{a^2+b^2+c^2},\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2},0)$ should be expressed as $(0,1,0)$, so for $V_1$ we can set $a=1, b,c$ to $0$ is this the idea?

Comment: And sry one more ting you wrote If $P_E$ is the orthogonal projection onto E we get $P_E(v_1)=v_1, P_E(v_2)=v_2, P_E(v_3)=0$ because $v_1,v_2 \in E$ and $v_3\bot E$. How do you know that ?

Comment: So, you obtained $\frac1a$ times $(1,0,0)$. Then $e_1:=a(v_3-bv_1-cv_2)=(1,0,0)$: the first standard basis vector is expressed as a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ (with coefficients $a,-ab,-ac$ but it doesn't matter much). Then I meant to use this and use linear combination to express the other two standard basis vectors. For example $(a^2+b^2+c^2)v_1+\frac ba e_1$ has zero first and third coordinates: it's parallel to $(0,1,0)$. Have you verified that $v_1,v_2\in E$ and that they are both orthogonal to $v_3$?

Comment: Hey thanks so much for helping me so far. Sorry i feel really dumb now. Gotta ask now we proved that the set B is a generator for $\Bbb R^3$ we still need to prove that the set is linearly independent right? for it to be a basis?...................And i was just checking if $v_1,v_2 \in E$ but ... sry i dont know how to do it.....as for orthogonality i tried to use the dot product $v_1*v_2$ but it didnt output 0---

Comment: I stated $v_1\perp v_3$ and $v_2\perp v_3$. If you have $n$ vectors that generate an $n$ dimensional space, they're a basis

Comment: Ah sorry, i got it now yes now i showed $v_1\bot v_3$ and $v_2\bot v_3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131248/discussion-between-jerry-cohen-and-berci).

Comment: hey im so sorry to call you up on this again....Just really want to make sure that i understood this....To part b): if the coordinates third row of $P_E$ in the basis of B is (0,0,0) that means its (0,0,0) relative to any basis right? So that would make the matrix in the standard basis $(\frac{-b/a}{a^2+b^2+c^2},\frac{-c/a}{a^2+b^2+c^2},0),(\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2},0,0$ and $(0,0,0)$ would that be correct? And ker(P_E) would be (-c, -b,0)? Would really appreciate this!!!

Comment: The kernel was already found, it's the set of scalar multiples of $(a,b,c)$, or equivalently, of $v_3$. To answer b) recall how the standard basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ was expressed by $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Based on this, using linearity, you should be able to obtain $P_E(e_i)$ for each $i=1,2,3$. They are in original coordinates which means, by the standard basis. Write these 3 results in columns. None of them will be zero.

Comment: oh yeah right thank you.....Thou we established $P_E(v_1)=v_1, P_E(v_2)=v_2$ and there are $0$s in these vectors....How come there is no 0 in the new matrix....And the third vector in the basis of B is already (0,0,0) so they are (0,0,0) in any basis right?

Comment: We definitely have $P_E(v_3)=0$, yes, it's $0$ in any basis, but $v_3$ is not in the standard basis. What I mean is $P_E(e_i)\ne 0$. Your misconception might be again that the change of basis happens both in the domain and in the codomain. If you calculate well, the other matrix should share a lot of properties (rank, nullity, characteristic polynomial, etc.) with the first matrix. Having a zero column is not among these properties..

Comment: ehmmm sry im lost again.....Do i need to now calculate P_E by using the orthogonal projection formula and then calculate the coordinates in the standard basis?

Comment: To get the matrix in basis $\beta=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, you plug in $v_i$ into the transformation $P_E$ and coordinatize the results in $\beta$. To get the matrix in basis $\gamma=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ you plug in $e_i$ in the same transformation $P_E$ and coordinatize the results in $\gamma$. Recall to my sentence starting with 'recall'.

Comment: but i dont yet have the the coordinates for $P_E$ right? I can still use $P_E(v1)=v1$ and change the basis to $e_1$? but what shall i do with the 3rd vector since v3 is not in $P_E$

Comment: Please do the recall.

Comment: i got a new matrix $(\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2+c^2},0,0),(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2+c^2},1,0),(0,0,1)$   Is this correct?

Comment: No. You need the exact coefficients $\lambda_i$ in expressed $e_1=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2 v_2+\lambda_3 v_3$. Based on this you'll have $P_E(e_1)=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2$. Same for $e_2$ and $e_3$.

Comment: So $(-b,-c,0), (a^2+b^2+c^2+c/a,0,0),(0,a^2+b^2+c^2+c/a,0)$

Comment: Still not. For simplification, you can work with $w_1=(-\frac ba,1,0),\ w_2=(-\frac ca,0,1),\ w_3=(a,b,c)$, these are parallel to $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Express the standard basis elements $e_1=(1,0,0),\ e_2=(0,1,0),\ e_3=(0,0,1)$ as linear combinations of $w_1,w_2,w_3$. What coefficients do you have? (See 4th comment up here )

Comment: exactly the coordinates from w1 w2 and w3?

Comment: That's the other direction. The coefficients of $w_i$ when writing as linear combination of $e_j$'s are indeed just its original coordinates.

Comment: ohhhh flip the numbers? $(-a/b,1,0), (-a/c,0,1),(1/a,1/b,1/c)$ ouh wait.....so if they are the linear combination of standard basis, then thats the answer, no?

Comment: No. Please follow my suggestions otherwise it makes it much harder. Have you found the 4th comment? That helps you get started how to express $e_1$ with $w_i$. Namely: $w_3-bw_1-cw_2$ is parallel to $e_1$. Specifically then $e_1=$...??

Comment: So if $w_3-bw_1-cw_2=1/a$ then $e_1=1=a*1/a$?

Comment: $a_1(w_3-bw_1-cw_2)$? Ok im dumb...

Comment: Well, if you calculate correctly and use common denominator ($a$), then you should get $w_3-bw_1-cw_2=(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}a,\,0,0)=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}a\cdot(1,0,0)$. So, $e_1=\frac a{a^2+b^2+c^2}(w_3-bw_1-cw_2)$. Now we know $P_E(w_1)=w_1,\ P_E(w_2)=w_2,\ P_E(w_3)=0$ and that $P_E$ is linear, so $P_E(e_1)=-\frac a{a^2+b^2+c^2}(bw_1+cw_2)$. Substitute the coordinates of $w_1,w_2$ to get the first column of $P_E$ written in standard basis. To express $e_2,e_3$ use what you already got for $e_1$. To verify your result matrix: each column should be in $E$.

Comment: I will go over this until i fully understand. Thank you so much for helping me. It must have taken you a lot of time! Really, thank you!